# Falling dominoes ode??

Tags: physics

I am doing a modelling project and my teacher told my group to modelling falling dominoes. In order to do that, we need to know which forces exists in this system but we cannot figure out which force is not included in our model because it doesnt work.

I have to say that we are allowed to use any bibliography, so if you know any please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like more of a question for [the physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You might wanna consider momentum instead of forces, and analysing collisions.

Answer (score 1):

The dominoes do not exert continuous forces on each other, rather there is a discrete impulse transmitted when one domino hits the next.  It may be useful to assume that, at least initially, the domino pivots without slipping around the line where its outward face meets the floor.